# Copies of a fixed graph in a random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I don't understand why the number of copies of a fixed graph H in a random graph with $n$ vertices and edges chosen with probability $p$ is:

$$\Theta(n^{v(H)}p^{e(H)})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that $v(H)$ and $e(H)$ are the number of vertices and edges of $H$, respectively, and I'll abbreviate them as $v$ and $e$ because $H$ is fixed here.  Any copy of $H$ in your random graph $G$ is given by a one-to-one map $f$ of the vertices of $H$ to those of $G$ such that, whenever $a$ and $b$ are adjacent vertices of $H$ then $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are adjacent in $G$.  The number of one-to-one maps $f$ (ignoring for the moment any adjacency requirements) is $n(n-1)\cdots(n-v+1)$, which is $\Theta(n^v)$ (because $v$ is fixed while $n$ grows).  The adjacency requirement is, of course, satisfied by only a fraction of these $f$'s.  For any particular edge $ab$ of $H$, the probability that $f(a)f(b)$ is an edge of $G$ is, by assumption, $p$, and these events for different edges $ab$ are independent.  So the probability that $f$ has all $e$ of the required adjacency properties is $p^e$.  So we have $\Theta(n^vp^e)$, but we're not quite done yet.  The one remaining issue is that several $f$'s might produce the same copy of $H$ in $G$.   Specifically, if $i:H\to H$ is an automorphism of $H$, then if either of $f\circ i$ and $f$ produces a copy of $H$ in $G$ then the other will produce the same copy.  So we have to correct our count of copies of $H$ in $G$ by dividing by the number of automorphisms of $H$.  Fortunately, as $H$ is fixed, we're just dividing by a constant, so the final result is still $\Theta(n^vp^e)$.